# Rails 3: A question about array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a question about that:

```
@st = exam.students.find(:all)
@st.each do |student|
```

Return me an array with all student, but:

```
exam.students.each do |student|
```

Return me an array with 4 times each students

Here is a print

[print](http://www.freepicsup.com/?v=x.png)

Anyone have an idea about that?

UPDATE:

Here is my Exam Model:

```
set_table_name "exam"
set_primary_key "ID_Exam"

belongs_to :questionnaire, :foreign_key => "ID_Questionnaire"

has_many :responses, :foreign_key => "ID_Exam"
has_many :students, :through => :responses, :foreign_key => "ID_Exam", :group => "response.ID_Student" 

belongs_to :professor, :foreign_key => "ID_Professor"

has_many :student_exam_times
has_many :exam_halted_students
has_many :exam_paused_students
has_many :answered_questions
```

And this my Student Model:

```
set_table_name "student"
set_primary_key "ID_Student"

has_one :user, :foreign_key => "ID_User"

has_many :group_student, :foreign_key => "ID_Student", :group => "group_student.ID_Group"
has_many :groups, :through => :group_student, :foreign_key => "ID_Group"

has_many :responses, :foreign_key => "ID_Student"
has_many :exams, :through => :responses, :foreign_key => "ID_Exam", :group => "exam.ID_Exam"

has_many :student_exam_times
has_many :exam_halted_students
has_many :exam_paused_students
has_many :marked_questions
has_many :answered_questions

has_many :messages, :order => "viewed ASC, send_at DESC"
```

UPDATE 2:

Here is my block:

```
    students_exam = exam.students.find(:all)
    students_exam.each do |student|
      cont=StudentExamTime.find(:first,:conditions => {:student_id => student.id, :exam_id => params[:exam_id].to_i })
      bd_time=0
      if cont==nil
        cont=StudentExamTime.new
      else
        bd_time=cont.time
      end
      cont.student_id=student.id
      cont.exam_id=params[:exam_id].to_i
      cont.time=bd_time + params[:time].to_i
      cont.save
    end
```

Comment: that's weird, what does `exam.students.count` say?

Comment: Hi, thx for your response. exam.students.count return 12 and 3 for exam.students.find(:all)

Comment: hi, can you post the `has_many` association in the exam model? And check your database table with the mysql admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:uniq => true`

to

```
has_many :students, :through => :responses, :foreign_key => "ID_Exam", :group => "response.ID_Student"
```

in your exam model

Comment: Thanks, it works fine ! Do you have an explication why whitout ":uniq => true" exam.students return each students 4 times?

Comment: What uniq does is it adds distinct to the select query. Your query based on the joins is returning not just the uniq rows but all the rows that it this will match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the relationships in your Exam model?

My initial feeling is that you have more-complex-than-typical relationship between exam and students that could benefit from a "DISTINCT" declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `exam.students` is returning every student with that associated exam (even duplicates)

Whereas `exam.students.find(:all)` is returning a list of unique students.

What does your model relation look like and your table setup?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion your block within

```
exam.students.each do |student|
```

is returning an array of 4 students. can you post that block too.